# Building matrices of 0’s and 1’s

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

How would I go about computing the number of ways an nxn matrix of 1’s and 0’s can be made such that every nxm  submatrix has more rows containing 1’s than the number of columns m?

Comment: related: [Number of n X n (0,1)-matrices with zero permanent](https://oeis.org/A088672)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
n=4;m=3;
f[mat_]:=Count[Map[Max,mat],1]>m;
allmat=Partition[Tuples[{0,1},n^2],n];
allsubmat=Flatten[Map[Table[#[[1;;n,i;;i+m-1]],{i,1,n-m+1}]&,allmat],1];
Count[Map[f,allsubmat],True]
```

which instantly returns `28672`

`f` tests whether a matrix has more than `m` rows containing 1. `allmat`contains all possible matricies of 0 and 1. `allsubmat` contains all possible submatricies. And the last line uses `f` on each of those matricies to count how many satisfy `f`.

You must test this carefully to make certain that I've made no mistakes. Try `f` on a few matricies that you make up to see if it works as expected. Look at the contents of `allmat` for a few small values of `n` and see if you can verify it makes a list of correct matricies and has all of them. Check `Length[allmat]` and decide if that is the correct number. Then check the next line to see if it correctly finds all submatricies. Check `Length[allsubmat]` and decide if that is the correct number. And finally try to verify the last line finds the correct total.

For larger values of `n` and `m` this may use a lot of memory and take a lot of time.